# SQLAlchemy - Postgres Connection Issue while running via Flask

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, database-connection, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask with SQLAlchemy 
Flask==0.10.1
SQLAlchemy==1.0.8

In production after a lot of usages (connection) we are getting this error. After that restarting the server helps, what will be the permanent solution

OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly\n\tThis probably means the server terminated abnormally\n\tbefore or while processing the request.\

Similarly, we are creating a scoped session, we are doing session.close()

**I tried Null Pool which doesn't help**

Any ideas on that?

Relevant finding
[Is it odd that my SQLAlchemy MySQL connection always ends up sleeping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824826/is-it-odd-that-my-sqlalchemy-mysql-connection-always-ends-up-sleeping)

[Handle mysql restart in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033234/handle-mysql-restart-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Why someone downvoted? I tried something on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to handle it in SQLAlchemy Dealing Disconnect

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects